# How to read a BerkeleyDB file with PHP?

Tags: php, berkeley-db

Well i have a berkeleydb file and i wish to parse it with php. Are there any examples i could use on how to do this?

The only catch is, the file is huge, like 500+ megabytes(and rising to this day).

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3073342/does-anyone-have-any-experience-using-berkeley-db-with-php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The use of the [DBA functions](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.dba.php) along with the appropriate handler (db2, db3, or db4) will allow you to use BDB files.

Comment: May you define what you mean with the "appropriate handler"?

Comment: Please read the linked documentation first and then come back with questions.

Answer (score 1):

If you download the full source from the Oracle website ([link](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/berkeleydb/downloads/index.html)) it comes with a very simple PHP demonstration as well as source code for the driver.